# Adding header of the first file to all the other split files in Perl

Tags: perl

I need to add header of the first main file to all the split files. i.e I am able to get header for the 1st split file but i need it for all the split files, here I am splitting DAT file. Below is what i have done so for:

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w

my $chunksize  = 25000000; # 25MB
my $filenumber = 0;
my $infile     = "Test.dat";
my $outsize    = 0;
my $eof        = 0;

my $line = $_;

open INFILE, $infile;
open OUTFILE, ">outfile_".$filenumber.".dat";

while (<INFILE>) {
    chomp;

    if ($outsize > $chunksize) {

        close OUTFILE; 
        $outsize = 0;
        $filenumber++;

        open (OUTFILE, ">outfile_".$filenumber.".dat")
            or die "Can't open outfile_".$filenumber.".dat";

    }

    print OUTFILE "$_\n";
    $outsize += length;
}
close INFILE;
```

Comment: Can you give us example input and expected output, assuming a smaller chunk size?

Comment: Please add pragma `use strict;` to your script

Answer (score 4):

- You should *always* `use warnings` (in preference to the command-line `-w`) and  `use strict`. That way many simple errors that you may otherwise have obverlooked will be flagged
- Use the three-parameter form of `open` with lexical filehandles
- Check the result of *all* open calls and flag errors containing the value of `$!` in a `die` string
- Define *constant* values with the `use constant` pragma father than as Perl variables
- The number of bytes printed to a filehandle can be evaluated using the `tell` function, so there is no need to keep your own count

To solve your specific problem, you should read and remember the first line of your input file, and print it to new output files every time they are opened

It is easier to keep track of the output files if you `open` them when you have new data to write and no open file, and `close` them when they are full or if you have reached the end of the input data

This program demonstrates the ideas and does what is required

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant INFILE    => 'Test.dat';
use constant CHUNKSIZE => 25_000_000;  # 25MB

open my $infh, '<', INFILE or die $!;

my $header = <$infh>;

my $outfh;
my $filenumber = 0;

while (my $line = <$infh>) {

  unless ($outfh) {
    my $outfile = "outfile_$filenumber.dat";
    open $outfh, '>', $outfile or die "Can't open '$outfile': $!";
    print { $outfh } $header;
    $filenumber++;
  }

  print { $outfh } $line;

  if (tell $outfh > CHUNKSIZE or eof $infh) {
    close $outfh or die $!;
    undef $outfh;
  }
}
```

Comment: Woww....thats wonderful!!!...This really saved my time. Thank you so much Borodin,Zaid and everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the header from the input file and print it every time a new file is opened:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

# initializations ...

open my $in,  '<', $infile;
open my $out, '>', "outfile_${file_number}.dat";

my $header = <$in>;    # Save the header...
chomp $header;         # ... not strictly necessary

while ( <$in> ) {

    chomp;             # Not strictly necessary

    if ( $outsize > $chunksize) {

        close $out; 
        $outsize = 0;
        $filenumber++;

        open $out, '>', "outfile_${file_number}.dat";

        print $out $header, "\n";    # Prints header at beginning of file
                                     # Newline needed if $header chomped

    }

    print $out $_, "\n";             # Newline needed if $_ chomped
    $outsize += length;
}
```

Comment: I would avoid chomping then you don't need the "\n" when you print out

Comment: @justintime : Hence the 'not strictly necessary' comments